# Excluding two columns in IF functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I'm doing a for where I want to exclude both 'date' and 'unix' columns from the data frame.

How can I do it?

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from tensortrade.data.cdd import CryptoDataDownload 
import pandas as pd

cdd = CryptoDataDownload()

data = cdd.fetch("Bitstamp", "USD", "BTC", "1h")

for col in data.columns:
  if col !=  'date' and 'unix' :
    data[col]=data[col].pct_change()
    data.dropna(inplace=True)
    data[col] = preprocessing.scale(data[col].values)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For test multiple values is possible use `in` with `list`:

```
if col not in ['date', 'unix']:
```

Another idea for your solution with [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) for all columns without specified in list, then is used [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), removed missing rows and last normalized:

```
cols = data.columns.difference(['date', 'unix'])
data[cols]=data[cols].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change())
data = data.dropna(subset=cols)
data[cols]=data[cols].apply(lambda x: preprocessing.scale(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the whole condition if you want to add a second one in your `if` statement.

```py
list_ = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

for elem in list_:
    if elem != "a" and "b":
        print(elem)
# Output : b, c, d

for elem in list_:
    if elem != "a" and elem != "b":
        print(elem)
# Output : c, d
```

This translates :

```py
for col in data.columns:
  if col !=  'date' and col != 'unix' :
    print(col)
```